# Retrieving Data from a remote XML File and add to datagrid

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that I have no write access to it .. I retrieve it online.

I have the code below, which works fine, but I can't move forward ..

```
using System.Data;
using System.Xml.Linq;


try
{
    XDocument XMLFile = XDocument.Load(@"http://Domain/path/to/file.xml");
    MessageBox.Show("Remote File Loaded Successfully ...");
    var items = XMLFile.Descendants("item");
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        i++;
        //var title = item.Descendants("title");
        //MessageBox.Show(title.ToString());
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Items Found: " + i);
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
}
```

The problem I'm facing is in the `foreach` loop. Every root element item has some child elements. I can't figure out how to retrieve those elements!!

Also, I have a grid view, I want to add the result to it, how can I achieve that??

Thank.

***EDIT***

XML Sample:

```
<item>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>http://domain/link</link>
    <description>Some Text</description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 05 Dec 2012 01:29:37 -0500</pubDate>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">Domain_text_INTEGER</guid>
    <category domain="http://domain/link">A</category>
    <category domain="http://domain/link">B</category>
    <category domain="http://domain/link">C</category>
    <category domain="http://domain/link">D</category>
    <category domain="http://domain/link">E</category>
    <coop:keyword>A</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>B</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>C</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>D</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>E</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>text integer</coop:keyword>
    <coop:keyword>Text</coop:keyword>
</item>
```

What I need from it:

- Title
- Link
- Description
- PubDate
- Guid (INTEGER) <= I can get the integer from the string OR text integer

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the sample XML file ?

Comment: Try reading up on xpath querying - it makes it fairly easy to traverse and extract data from xml

Comment: Habib: Updated // trebuchet: Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

So on your XMLfile XDocument you've got the descendants.

Also create a collection

```
List<someobject> list = new List<someobject>();
```

So in your loop

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var someObject = new SomeObject()
    {
        Title = item.Element("title").Value
    }
}
```

Then bind your collection to the Grid

Answer (score 0):

This [MSDN topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/xmlandnetfx/thread/ceb3b540-2b91-4699-a5c7-16a13b674305) could help you. On MSDN they are posted [Walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekw4dh3f%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) of your problem. Both links suggest to use dataset for this:

```
DataSet dsAuthors = new DataSet("authors");
string filePath = "Complete path where you saved the XML file";
dsAuthors.ReadXml(filePath);
dataGrid1.DataSource = dsAuthors;
dataGrid1.DataMember = "authors";
dataGrid1.CaptionText = dataGrid1.DataMember;
```

I just copy/paste an example. You need to modify it for your purposes.

Comment: That would help I guess if I use the whole file .. but I'm just using some elements and some of their sub elements!