# Displaying 2D Array in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D Array that I created to hold the data referenced in this question ["Retrieving Data from a remote XML File and add to datagrid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757760/retrieving-data-from-a-remote-xml-file-and-add-to-datagrid)

**My Array:**

```
string[,] myData = new string[i,6];
```

The string is populated just fine and I can retrieve the data from it and was able to confirm it using:

```
MessageBox.Show(myData[0, 0], "Title");
MessageBox.Show(myData[0, 2], "Description");
```

Now, I have a `DataGrid` named `projects`

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="projects" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="264" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" />
</Grid>
```

How can I bind the 2D Array to the DataGrid?

Comment: Google does wonders: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5806/Binding-a-two-dimensional-array-to-a-DataGrid

Comment: and what about the headers?

Comment: btw, thanks for the link :)